# Issue about Android understanding VpnService code

Tags: android

I have been learning Android VpnService and I found a good project to build Network Firewall using VpnService named NetGuard in Github https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/#netguard.
I have read the code in ServiceSinkhole, but I still can't understand how to block internet access in the code?
Could you please tell me where I can find the blocking way in the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "block Internet access"? I suggest you read the (comprehensive) documentation for the [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) and the [VpnService.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder) classes which explains how to set up the VPN tunnel using the provided API. Once the VPN is set up, you essentially have a "hook" into the network traffic of the Android device, hence you are fully in charge of what outbound packets exit the device, and what inbound packets are delivered to the applications. In other words, you can use this hook to drop packets as you like, thereby "blocking Internet access". This "hook" is the file descriptor returned by the call to [`VpnService.Builder.establish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#establish()):

> [...] The interface works on IP packets, and a file descriptor is returned
>   for the application to access them. Each read retrieves an outgoing
>   packet which was routed to the interface. Each write injects an
>   incoming packet just like it was received from the interface. [...]

In essence, to block an application's Internet access, simply avoid writing its outbound packets to the VPN tunnel (outbound packets are read from the file descriptor), **and** avoid writing its inbound packets to the file descriptor (inbound packets are read from the VPN tunnel).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have read VpnService and VpnService.Builder and I understand prepare() and establish(). According to your guidance, you suggested me finding the code about VPN tunnel and the code about file descriptor in the project? I found some code written as c file in JNI. Is that the corresponding code to block an application's internet access? I am just a new beginner in NDK. Thanks for your help and patience again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't feel like I have recent enough experience with JNI to help you with that part. Btw, for future questions, you might want to ask more precise questions (this one is very broad). E.g. show what you have coded so far and what issues you're facing. All the best, and good luck!